# Unity Netcode (Multiplayer) clients don't have ownership over their players

Tags: unity-game-engine, multiplayer

I have been working on a 3D multiplayer game using Unity Netcode, and have not been able to get clients to  move only their own character, however Hosts can use theirs as expected. The character controller uses a rigidbody which falls as expected.

I used:

```
if (!IsOwner) return;
```

but it does not seem to be working, although it should.

Thank you in advance for anyone who can help :)

Comment: With the 1 line of code you have shown, if you are not the owner then it returns and does nothing. Isn't that the whole reason why clients can't control players if they are not the host?